# Change password in parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an issue in implementing forgot password.
I want to change password of PFUser. I have email address only.

```
   PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:[txtUserID.text lowercaseString]];
    NSArray *arr=[query findObjects];
```

Now I try to change password.

```
PFUser *user = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
user.password=txtConfirmPassword.text;
[user save];
```

It says I need authentication to change password. For that I dont have password to login in first place.
Other way is using `requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground`. But It sends email and user need to click that link and set password. My client do not want that step. We have our another service which takes care of users by asking few questions like birthdate, mothers name etc.

I think there should be a way to login as administrator, who has read/write authority.

Anyone has used anything like that?
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: this would be back4app.com these days rather than Parse  :O

Comment: you have to do this using cloud code, and the master key

ie, Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

It is explained over and over on the Parse forum. Example,

https://www.parse.com/questions/custom-reset-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Resetting Passwords" section in the [Parse Docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-resetting/iOS).

You don't reset the passwords from the device. It is all done server side through the Parse "reset passwords" work flow.

i.e. request email for forgotten password, go to website, create new, etc.....

The only part done from the device is requesting the reset password email.

**EDIT**

For editing a password of a logged in user you will be able to use the code you have as you will have write access to the current user object.

Comment: Yes. I tried that. It sends a email. User need to click that link and change password. But my client don't want that step. We have our other service which validates user by asking some questions. So, is there a way to login as a admin or by using application key or something and change user's password.

Comment: As it's a potential massive security flaw I'm guessing not.

Comment: I dont have access to current user, as if application is deleted and installed again, or if my friend is using my phone to login and reset password.

Comment: The fact is, you chose parse as an authentication framework and back end DB. Along with that choice you chose to use the password reset system that they supply. I really don't think you're gonna get round it. The whole point of a password is that it's secure. If you're allowed to change it when not logged in then that's just bad. What happens if a random person steals your phone and changes the password etc... If you don't like the workflow then there are many other BAAS frameworks to choose from. Parse, probably isn't the right one.

Comment: You, the site administrator, can literally change the password ON THE DASHBOARD -- JUST TYPE IN A NEW PASSWORD.  ok?

Comment: Everything @Fog says is of course correct.  Ah - he's looking for the **master key in cloud code.**