# Cannot save User class objects in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

```
- (IBAction)savePasswordButton:(id)sender {
    PFObject *myPassword = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"_User"];
    myPassword[@"password"] = self.myPasswordfield.text;
    [myPassword saveInBackground];
}
```

The problem is here: For the _User class I can't see anything in the databrowser, but when I try with other classes it works successfully

Does anyone could explain me where am I wrong ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change password in parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736089/change-password-in-parse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Parse documentation, 'User' is a built-in class.

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
user.password = self.myPasswordfield.text;
[user saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Ah yes ! This is the prove that I don't know well the documentation, thank you !

Comment: Please refer to Parse's documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS It's pretty much straightfoward.